# How to use jQuery UI Autocomplete with multiple values with Oracle ApEx?

Tags: jquery, oracle, jquery-ui, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Application Express (ApEx v3.0.1) and I would like to use jQuery UI – Autocomplete with Multiple values example.

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Basically, looking at the source for this example, it has the following variable dataset:

```
        var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
```

What I would like to do and unsure how to do with Oracle ApEx is reference a database table via an on-demand process and retrieve customer names where I would like a user to select multiple values from or even just a single value.

The only issue too though is, this table has over 90,000 records and so not sure what the best way to do this.

Pretty much, I would like to do it like Stack Overflow does it when choosing the tags for a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function as the [`source` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source):

```
$(stuff).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/your/autocompleter?pat=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term),
          type: 'get',
          success: function(data) {
              response(data.split('\n'));
          },
          // Other AJAX options as needed
      }),
      // Other autocomplete options as needed
});
```

Then, `/your/autocompleter` would get what they've currently entered in the `pat` parameter and use that to query your database to find possible matches. To get the possible matches back to the autocompleter, you'd just have to return the possible matches as a list of strings — one match per line — with a content type of `text/plain`. You don't need to use the "one per line" plain text format but that's probably the easiest, you only need to ensure that the success callback can parse the `/your/autocompleter` return data into an array to hand to `response`.